# Изменение цвета иконок при переключении темы и грамотное подтягивание иконок из ресурсов

Tags: android

В своем приложении я реализовываю для пользователя возможность выбирать тему оформления. Делаю это через PreferenceActivity. Проблема заключается в том, что значки toolbara не реагируют на переключение темы.[image: toolbarDark][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/dots_vertical"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/settings"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

```
<resources>
<style name="AppThemeLight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryLight</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarkLight</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentLight</item>

    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/ActionButtonOverflow</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/ActionButtonOverflowLight</item>
</style>


<style name="ActionButtonOverflowLight" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_dots_vertical_white_24dp</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionButtonOverflow" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_dots_vertical_black_24dp</item>
</style>
```

На просторах SO много разных советов, но там или использовать другую родительскую (но у меня кастомный тулбар, поэтому не могу применить допустим Theme.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar) или же обходные пути, наподобие как у меня к коде выше - создать кастомную тему и прописать туда иконку. (это тоже не сработало).

Также дело в том, что в моем другом приложении тема менялась при выборе пункта меню. У меня в ресурсах лежал пакет с разными размерами и цветами

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и в меню просто прописывала android:icon="@drawable/dots_vertical" (без размера и цвета),все работало. А в способах обхода моей настоящей проблемы нужно прописывать @drawable/ic_dots_vertical_black_24dp. Но ведь приложение будет использоваться на разных экранах и если я правильно понимаю система сама будет тянуть приемлемый ресурс.

Поэтому хочется сделать не лишь бы работало, а грамотно. Специалисты, помогите разобраться

Comment: Может проблема в том, что вы задаете стиль вашему тулбаре в xml разметке?

Comment: Нет, там не задаю.

Answer (score 2):

Для выполнения того, что ты хочешь необходимо необходимо первым делом определить свой кастомный атрибут в файле **values/attr.xml**:

```
<attr name="menu_icon" format="reference" />
```

Этот атрибут будет отвечать за нашу иконку. Значение этого атрибута необходимо прописать в твоих темах, где он будет принимать разрые иконки в зависимости от тем:

```
<style name="AppThemeLight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryLight</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarkLight</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentLight</item>

    <item name="menu_icon">@drawable/ic_dots_vertical_white_24dp</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

    <item name="menu_icon">@drawable/ic_dots_vertical_black_24dp</item>
</style>
```

После этого указываешь его в меню, в значение **android:icon="?menu_icon"**, где **?** означает что мы значение берем из кастомного атрибута - значение берется из темы:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/settings"
    android:icon="?menu_icon"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/settings"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```