# Смена цвета иконки навигации в PrefenceActivity при смене темы приложения

Tags: android

В приложении пользователь может изменить тему оформления. Для этого я использую SettingFragment, который запускает SettingActivity (чтобы был тулбар)

```
public class SettingsActivity extends BaseActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.settings_with_toolbar);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
   if (toolbar != null) toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.keyboard_backspace);
    if (getActionBar() != null) getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Кнопка назад во всех темах черная.

Я пробовала прописывать код:

```
 if (toolbar != null && Constants.THEME_CHANGE.equals"dark") toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.keyboard_backspace_black);
else if (toolbar != null && Constants.THEME_CHANGE.equals"light") toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.keyboard_backspace_white);
```

кнопка остается черной.

Также прописывала в стилях 
`<item name="colorControlNormal">#FFFFFF</item>` тоже не работает.

ну и style.xml

```
 <style name="AppThemeLight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryLight</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarkLight</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentLight</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Описывал этот процесс тут: [Как задать цвет иконок при переключении темы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/876183/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7/876205#876205). В вопросе была смена  иконок для меню, в твоем случае необходимо кастомный атрибут ставить в **toolbar** для **navigation icon**. Пример тулбара:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/mainToolbar"
    app:navigationIcon="?menu_icon"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

где **app:navigationIcon="?menu_icon"** кастомный атрибут, значение которого возьмется из темы.